# Phonegap Splash screen - Android

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen, phonegap

This question has been asked in the past but none of the answers that I have found have solved the problem for me.

I try to add splash screen to my PhoneGap application and it works great in iOS, but not in Android.

```
<icon src="icon.png" />

    <splash src="splash.png" />

    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
```

Important to note, I work with this tool to generate the codes and splash images:
phonegap.appiq.software

Thank you!

Comment: is it displaying blank screen instead of your image?

Comment: Yes, it displaying black screen by the theme.

Comment: i faced same issue. What i had done is set drawable directly in java file of plugin.

Comment: Can you expand more please?

Comment: Can you please share link of plugin you are using?

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157447/discussion-between-samir-bhatt-and-ramirez).

Answer (score 0):

Check Plugin file on following path. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java

Debug on line no 296. Check if you are getting drawable or not.

```
splashImageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
```